Connect Pentaho to Oracle ADW using Wallet
I am trying to connect Pentaho Kettle to Oracle ADW using cwallet. I tried setting up from jar files but no luck
I tried following step from this link
https://holowczak.com/configuring-pentaho-data-integration-to-use-the-oracle-wallet-for-oracle-cloud/4/
but could not Locate the custom.properties file found in the data-integration\system\karaf\etc\ folder.
Any help on the process
Should be able to connect to Oracle ADW from Pentaho PDI
